# Какое указывать exntension в настройках phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

В файле настроек phpMyAdmin есть строка

```
cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']
```

В ней могут быть значения mysql или mysql**i**
Если я в PHP-скриптах всё равно работаю с БД через PDO_MYSQL, то что мне указывать тут?
Как я понял, лучше mysql**i**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli не всегда может быть установлен на хостинге, как это не странно. то что вы работаете используя PDO никак не влияет на phpMyAdmin. как итог ставьте mysqli если будет ошибка исправьте на mysql.

P.S. особой разницы в работе не заметил. хотя везде пишут, что c mysqli работа в phpMyAdmin полноценна, из за mysql 5+ и php 5+

Comment: Спасибо, я так и думал.